# Connect kafka in go(sarama), the consumer can not get message through topic

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I just want to follow a demo to try use kafka in go. I can successfully produce message by sarama, but when i want to consume the message, can not get it.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Shopify/sarama"
)

// kafka consumer

func main() {
    consumer, err := sarama.NewConsumer([]string{"127.0.0.1:9092"}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("fail to start consumer, err:%v\n", err)
        return
    }
    partitionList, err := consumer.Partitions("test") 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("fail to get list of partition:err%v\n", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(partitionList)
    for partition := range partitionList { 
        pc, err := consumer.ConsumePartition("test", int32(partition), sarama.OffsetNewest)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("failed to start consumer for partition %d,err:%v\n", partition, err)
            return
        }
        defer pc.AsyncClose()
        go func(sarama.PartitionConsumer) {
            for msg := range pc.Messages() {
                fmt.Printf("Partition:%d Offset:%d Key:%v Value:%v", msg.Partition, msg.Offset, msg.Key, msg.Value)
            }
        }(pc)
    }
}
```

The return of the code is

```
[0]
-1
```

But actually i can get the message through kafka-console-consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not wating for the messages to come...

here is the list fo issues you have in your code:

1. `defer pc.AsyncClose()` will trigger on function exit, not scope exit.
2. goroutine is launching into nowhere... nothing blocks or wait for the results to come.

```
       go func(sarama.PartitionConsumer) {
            for msg := range pc.Messages() {
                fmt.Printf("Partition:%d Offset:%d Key:%v Value:%v", msg.Partition, msg.Offset, msg.Key, msg.Value)
            }
        }(pc)
```

3. not passing argument to goroutine. `go func(sarama.PartitionConsumer) {` this is only type.  `go func(pc sarama.PartitionConsumer) {`.

Remove goroutine, and just check the consumer channel if you want to make `hello world` example.